# A curious feature of envelope of one parametric family of lines

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analytic-geometry

Envelope of one parametric family of lines $y=mx+f(m)$ is claimed to touch the given family of lines. I find/list five cases of lines and their respective envelopes below:

\begin{matrix} [1]:  y=mx+e^{-m} &  \rightarrow y=-x(\ln{x}-1) \\ [2]:  y=mx+\sin m &  \rightarrow y=x \cos^{-1}(-x)+\sqrt{1-x^2} \\ [3]: y=mx+m^3  & \rightarrow y=\frac{2x \sqrt{-x}}{3\sqrt{3}} \\ [4]: y = mx+m^2 &\rightarrow y = \frac{-x^2}{4} \\ [5]:
  y = mx+\cos m & \rightarrow y = \sqrt{1-x^2}+x\sin^{-1}(x) \end{matrix}

I find that in [1] and [4] $m$ can take any real value for a line to touch its envelope. In other cases $m$ is restricted: In case [2], $m \in [0,\pi]$. In case [3], $m \in [0,\infty).$ In case [5], $m\in [-\pi/2, \pi/2].$ I would like to know why and when $m$ gets restricted to a smaller domain than that of the real set. Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be useful to take just one specific example and work with it. Clearly, the first line is the tangent to the second equation in the list. You could start with case 3, for example. Take first
$$
f(x) = \frac{2x \sqrt{-x}}{3\sqrt{3}} \qquad x \leq 0
$$
and try to find the tangent at some $x_0$. The derivative (slope of the tangent) is easy:
$$
f'(x_0) = \frac{\sqrt{-x_0}}{\sqrt{3}}
$$
This should encourage you to continue. In the end, you only have to set $m=x_0$.

Comment: This experience is ordinary. In every case we want all possible values of $m$  for which the line touches its respective envelope. We are not looking for a particular point of tangency. I hope my question is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The envelope of a family of lines given by $y=mx+f(m)...(1)$ is found as $x+f'(m)=0...(2)$ where $m=y'$ so one solves the ODE $x+f'(y')=0...(3)$ and gets the envelope as $y=g(x)$...(4). Its is crucial to note that the  domain of $g(x)$ and Eq. (2) simultaneously determine all the 
possible values of $m$ for which the line (1) will touch the fixed curve (envelope) given by Eq. (4).

Let us analyse  five interesting examples of yours, one by one.

[1]: $x=e^{-m}$ and the domain of $g(x)$ is $x \in (0, \infty)$. Hence $m$ can take any real value.

[2]: $x+\cos m=0 \Rightarrow m= \cos^{-1} (-x) \Rightarrow m \in [0,\pi]$ as the domain of $g(x)$ is $[-1,1]$.

[3]: $x+3m^2=0\Rightarrow m=\pm \sqrt{\frac{-x}{3}}$. In this case one should get two envelopes $y=\pm g(x), ~\mbox{for}~ x\le 0.$ So, for $m \ge 0$ the envelope is $y=+g(x)$ and for $m\le 0$ it is $y=-g(x).$ In your listing you have  missed out the second part.

[4]: $x+2m=0$ and the domain of $g(x)$ is $(-\infty, \infty).$ Hence $m \in (-\infty,\infty).$

[5]: $x-\sin m=0 \Rightarrow m=\sin^{-1} (x) \Rightarrow m \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ as the domain of $g(x)$ is $[1,1].$

You have made an interesting observation, keep it up. In this regard, one may see Clairaut equation (ODE):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation